# I am trying to serve my React build to node/express app but I am getting an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am still learning the whole MERN stack technology. I am trying to follow a tutorial to serve my Create React App build files to my backend but I keep getting error. The error I am getting is this:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\kingsley\Desktop\blogfullstack \api\public\index.html'
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

I served the react build files in a folder called `public` inside my server folder. The *index.html* file is there as well.

In my server *app.js* file, I wrote the following codes according to the course tutorial:

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')))
```

After the above codes, I have my API end points which are 9 in total such as:

```
app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoute);

app.get('/*', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
})

module.exports = app;
```

What could I be doing wrong? I would love to learn and fix this.

Comment: 1) How are you spinning up the front end and back end? 2) Your error indicates there is supposed to be a space after a directory name: `\blogfullstack \`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am running both on same port which is my backend port. Your second point is not clear to me, could you explain? Thanks

Comment: In your error message there is a space after a directory name so that questions me to think you have a space in your code. It should read as `blogfullstack\api` not `blogfullstack \api`

Comment: I just copied the error once more and it is like this: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\kingsley\Desktop\blogfullstack\api\public\index.html'